# extracting Nodes from a XML file and extending it. I get these errors Call to a member function addChild() on null?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Hey there i am trying to search specified numbers in an XML File. After that i would like to extend the file. I want the file look like this.

The original file looks like this.

```
<products>
     <product>
        <OrderingInfo>
            <item name="Part No.">12345 (text)</item>
            <item name="Part No.">12345IP (text)</item>
        </OrderingInfo>
        <varitems>
        </varitems>
    </product>

     <product>
        <OrderingInfo>
            <item name="Part No.">001 (text)</item>
            <item name="Part No.">002 (text)</item>
        </OrderingInfo>
        <varitems>
        </varitems>
     </product>
</products>
```

My desired output:

```
<products>
     <product>
        <OrderingInfo>
            <item name="Part No.">12345 (text)</item>
            <item name="Part No.">12345IP (text)</item>
        </OrderingInfo>
        <varitems>
            <item>
              <varno>14205</varno>
              <text>text</text>

            </item>
            <item>
              <varno>14205IP</varno>
              <text>text</text>
            </item>
        </varitems>
    </product>

     <product>
        <OrderingInfo>
            <item name="Part No.">001</item>
            <item name="Part No.">002</item>
        </OrderingInfo>
        <varitems>
            <item>
              <varno>001</varno>
            </item>
            <item>
              <varno>002</varno>
            </item>
        </varitems>
     </product>
</products>
```

First of all I go into the first product and getting the values of *OrderingInfo*. And then try to save them with a new Child. But it says:

> Call to a member function addChild() on null"

on that line:

```
$sxml->product[$i]->varitems->item[$l]->addChild('varno', $ordernr[0]);
```

However, when I do it like this (leaving `[$i]` by the product):

```
$sxml->product->varitems->item[$l]->addChild('varno', $ordernr[0]);
```

it works but adds everything in the first on.

I am completely out of ideas. I hope some one can help me Thank you!

$xml = simplexml_load_file("OriginalFile.xml") or die("Error: Cannot create object");
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement($xml->asXML());

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $XMLlenght; $i++) {

$length = count($xml->product[$i]->OrderingInfo->item);

for ($l = 0; $l < $length; $l++) {

    $sxml->product->varitems->addChild("item");

    $searchpattern = '/[0-9]*$/';
    preg_match($searchpattern, $xml->product[$i]->OrderingInfo->item[$l], $ordernr);
    if ($varnr[0] != '') {
        $sxml->product[$i]->varitems->item[$l]->addChild('varno', $ordernr[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: How does the original XML file look?

Comment: i added the original file

Comment: Great! Please post fuller code especially variable assignment. What is *$sxml*? Same as *$xml*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language to transform XML files which can be called with PHP's [php-xsl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.xsl.php) class. Specifically run the [Identity Transform](http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity) (to copy document as is) and then rewrite `<varitems>` to map over the ancestor `product/OrderingInfo /item` nodes:

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

  <xsl:template match="varitems">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::product/OrderingInfo/item">
          <item>
             <varno><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(., 
                     'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz!@#$%^&amp;*()', ''))"/></varno>
              <text><xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(translate(., '0123456789', ''))"/></text>
          </item>
        </xsl:for-each>  
    </xsl:copy>    
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**PHP**

```
$xml = new DOMDocument;
$xml->load('Input.xml');

$xsl = new DOMDocument;
$xsl->load('XSLTScript.xsl');

// Configure transformer
$proc = new XSLTProcessor;
$proc->importStyleSheet($xsl);

// Transform XML source
$newXML = new DOMDocument;
$newXML = $proc->transformToXML($xml);

// Output to console
echo $newXML;

// Output to file
file_put_contents('Output.xml', $newXML);
```

Comment: with XSLT i can get values out of my original File and set them into a new one like i did with my php code?

Comment: XSLT contains no data as it transforms the original input XML source. I would post the output here but it's exactly your desired result.

Comment: can i build prep_match() into the php file?

Comment: You can pass a parameter into XSLT with [setParameter](http://php.net/manual/en/xsltprocessor.setparameter.php). I saw you attempt regex. Show some more of XML that would need a numeric check on node value. Are their nodes with no number?

Comment: sometimes there is text behind the numbers and i would like to extract the numbers separated from the text. I added the xml and my desired output

Comment: See update using XSLT's [`translate()`](http://www.xsltfunctions.com/xsl/fn_translate.html) to parse out strings and special characters.

Comment: No it is not. XSLT 1.0 does not support regex, but latter 2.0+ does. However, php-xsl only uses XSLT 1.0 but PHP like any general purpose language can call any external XSLT processors like [Saxon/Xalan](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt/info).

Comment: okay i am trying to understand it and it doesn't match 100% because sometimes their are numbers with in the text and characters with the number is their any possibility to handle that?

Comment: Did you test this solution with that scenario? I added strings between numbers and `<varno>` extracts the numbers and `<text>` extracts the strings.

Comment: yes it works fine but i need it more detailed for example some numbers are: 12345XYZ and i need all of it is there any possibility to search for certain patterns?

Comment: You can use XSLT's `string-before()`, `contains()`, or `<xsl:if>` but again regex is only available for XSLT 2.0+, not supported with php-xsl. Also, you might need to ask a new question as this pattern matching strays from this post's extend XML file.

Comment: i handled the problem. But i got another one. I was trying to select the varno so that it is for every varitem the same. I tried it with `/*/product/OrderingInfo/item[1]` but this select the first row of OrderingInformation of the first product to every varitems? what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Again, please ask a new question as selecting nodes strays from this thread of extending XML.